# SQL - How do I set an ALIAS as a blank space?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, alias

For example:

```
SELECT id_pet AS 'number', name_pet AS (null | blank) FROM PETS
```

So what I want is no column title for name_pet in my table.

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please tell us **why**?

Comment: select col1 as \`a blank space\` from myTable

Comment: It's pretty odd, it's a scores table and there are many columns, and the scores column's names are just unnecesary.

Comment: but seriously, you have nulls you want to go to blanks? Or something else. Like, in a select stmt?

Comment: No, we're not talking about row values, just the column names.

Comment: the column names are what, blanks? You aren't describing this well for like a dozen viewers

Comment: I want column names to be blank, no column name at the SELECT query outcome.

Comment: That's a client display problem, not a SQL problem. In SQL*Plus, for example, you can suppress headings so only the data is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle

```
SELECT num_rows "ID", table_name AS " " FROM user_tables;
```

However, the client will ultimately display it to the user and how that copes with spaces is anyone's guess. It may require unique column names, so each column name might have varying numbers of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL:

`SELECT id_pet AS 'number', name_pet AS '' FROM PETS`

Comment: Does not work buddy, the column name says "Column 1", and successively "Column 2" and so on.

Comment: Are you using Oracle? I tested this with MySQL 10.1.13-MariaDB and columns appeared blank. Otherwise you could do `SELECT name_pet as ' ' FROM PETS`. Technically not blank but I think it's the closest you can get with Oracle.